# Can't get the body from a JSON WEB API request in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, asp.net-web-api, python-requests

I have a problem when I connect to my Web API because I can't get the body of the result.

this is my code:

```
import json,requests
url =('URL')
data={"Content-Type":"application/x-wwwform-urlencoded", "Authorization":"Valid JWT Token"}
myResponse1 = requests.get(url,data=data)
print ("status_code:"+ str(myResponse1.status_code))
print ("******************")
print ("text:"+ str(myResponse1.text))
print ("******************")
print ("encoding:"+ str(myResponse1.encoding))
print ("******************")
print ("json:"+ str(myResponse1.json))
print ("******************")
print ("content:"+ str(myResponse1.content))
print ("******************")
print ("body:"+ str(myResponse1.body))
```

Whit this output:

```
status_code:401
******************
text:
******************
encoding:None
******************
json:<bound method Response.json of <Response [401]>>
******************
content:b''
******************
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Carlo\Desktop\Web API\Log-In_API.py", line 28, in <module>
    print ("body:"+ str(myResponse1.body))
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'body'
```

Now I can't understand why, because when I try the API with Postman is giving me back a body result:
[image]

If you see the status in my result and in the picture we have a different one, but I don't really understand why seeing that I'm passing the same parameters

Comment: The answer is actually in the screenshot you provided. Postman shows headers section, but code does not use any custom headers, and feeds relevant dict into data parameter. Which, for GET requests, goes into url, I guess.

Comment: hey guys, can I ask you why I have a negative score on this question please? I'm trying to improve all my question but I don't really understand why I have a negative score on that one :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the Response object returned by `requests` indeed does not have an attribute called `body`, and the docs don't imply that it does.

You've already accessed the contents of the response when you print `myResponse1.content` and `myResponse1.text`.

Note, `json` is a method; if you want the contents as json, you need to call it: `myResponse1.json()`.

Also note, authorization and content-type are headers, not query parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you give headers as data

```
data={"Content-Type":"application/x-wwwform-urlencoded", "Authorization":"Valid JWT Token"}
myResponse1 = requests.get(url,data=data)
```

instead you should use argument headers

```
    headers={"Content-Type":"application/x-wwwform-urlencoded", "Authorization":"Valid JWT Token"}
    myResponse1 = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
```

And also the problem described by [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42532242/4175590)

Comment: I made this change but I still get an error, this and looks that I have an authentication problem but I don't really understand why because the information that I'm passing now are identical to Postman and with the headers instead than data :S

Comment: issue solved, was an authentication problem plus the headers. thanks so much